# Error : Sharepoint List access through Power Shell

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

Im getting "Cannot index into a null array" at line with  "$spWeb.List"

Im using Windows7 home premium and Sharepoint Foundation 2010

I tried to add the user to shell Add-SPShellAdmin -username -database .. failing informing
 error is that the account name was already added to the database as a login using a different user name than the account

Please suggest!.

```
"============================================================================="
$PSSnapin = Remove-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null
 $PSSnapin = Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |    Out-Null

$spWeb = Get-SPWeb http://krishna-hp:11944/sites/sh100/
$spList = $spWeb.List["products"] 

$newItem = $splist.Items.Add()

$newItem["Title"] = "this is title"
$newItem["product_id"] = 34
$newItem["product_desc"] = "this is from poershell"
$newItem["price"] = 123
$newItem.Update()
```

Answer (score 1):

Its simple Just changing the line

$spList = $spWeb.List["products"]

to

$spList = $spWeb.Lists["products"]    works out!